# Xamarin PCL project - My iOS app is not launching in iOS 12.1 and below ..its working well in 12.1 and above till latest 13.2

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, installation, ios11

Xamarin PCL project - My iOS app is not launching in iOS 12.1 and below ..its working well in 12.1 and above till latest 13.2..App installing well but when launching the app its not loading at all and unfortunately i am not able to get any crash logs also.

Comment: Open info.plist in iOS project . Check the value of **Deploymnet Target** .

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the stack trace that happens when the app crashes?